# Error 'LocalSimulator' with Googlecolab

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, simulation, amazon-braket

I have an error when I want to run the `'LocalSimulator'`. I am not inside AWS, its mean I runnig from Google Colab. The code is the same on the notebooks from [0_Getting_started](https://amazon-braket-conexionaws.notebook.us-east-1.sagemaker.aws/lab/tree/Braket%20examples/getting_started/0_Getting_started/0_Getting_started.ipynb)

```
    # general imports
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline

    # AWS imports: Import Braket SDK modules
    from braket.circuits import Circuit
    from braket.devices import LocalSimulator

    # build a Bell state with two qubits. Here 'cnot(control=0, target=1)' can be 
     simplified as 'cnot(0,1)'
    bell = Circuit().h(0).cnot(control=0, target=1)
    # set up device
    device = LocalSimulator()

    # run circuit
     result = device.run(bell, shots=1000).result()
    # get measurement shots
    counts = result.measurement_counts
    # print counts
    print(counts)
```

And the result is

`ValueError: Only the following devices are available dict_keys([])`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Sandra, we have not been able to reproduce the issue on our side. Could you tell us if @ryanhill1's solution fixed the problem? Otherwise, do you mind providing more guidance on how to reproduce it? Thanks

Comment: oh! thanks. Yes the answer by @ryanhill1's worked.

Answer (score 2):

From the top-bar, click `Runtime` > `Restart session`, and then try again.

The error is coming from the [_simulator_devices](https://github.com/amazon-braket/amazon-braket-sdk-python/blob/d5af538079d9cbb6f065da46e1e6731145e2a71b/src/braket/devices/local_simulator.py#L41-L43) entry points dict returning empty when called on.

When you installed the amazon-braket-sdk in your Google Colab notebook, it registered its entry points in the environment. However, since Python's module system and the `pkg_resources` module in particular rely on internal caches for performance reasons, these new entry points weren't immediately visible to the already-running kernel. Restarting the kernel/session should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wasn't sure if AWS worked externally to their website. But it's currently working, so thank you very much. It was something simple.

Comment: @SandraRosales No problem! If my answer helped resolve could you mark it as accepted? Thanks!